# Derivative of $y=6xe^{6x}-e^{6x}$

Tags: derivatives

Can some one walk me through how to find the derivative of $y=6xe^{6x}-e^{6x}$?  
 I know the answer should be $36e^{6x}x$.  
 I know I am supposed to use the product and chain rule, I just don't understand where and how to tell they are applied. How do I know what part requires what?

Comment: How do you know that answer is right?

Comment: This is nearly identical [to this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436550/first-second-derivative-of-x2x34-y) The derivative of a sum or difference of functions is the sum or difference of the derivatives: $(f \pm g)' = f' \pm g'$.

Comment: Do you know what is logarithmic derivative?

Comment: Calculating derivatives is a mechanical exercise. Start walking, and we'll guide you.

Comment: First try to compute $e^{6x}$ by putting $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x) = 6x$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Rewrite as

$$y=(6x-1)e^{6x}$$

call $f(x)=6x-1$ and $g(x)=e^{6x}$ and use

$$(f\cdot g)'=f'\cdot g+f\cdot g'$$

In order to calculate $g'(x)$ you will need chain rule.

Then call $p(x)=6x$ and $q(x)=e^x$ and then $g(x)=q(p(x))$. Now use chain rule

$$g'(x)=p'(x)\cdot q'(p(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

Linearity of derivatives: $$\frac{d}{dx}(cf(x)+kg(x))=cf'(x)+kg'(x)\qquad c,k\in\Bbb R$$
Product rule: $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
Chain rule: $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
Recall, $$\frac{d}{du}e^u=e^u$$